# Cuando ejecuto un programa en visual Studio se cierra la terminal

Tags: c#, visual-studio

hace poco instale visual studio en mi pc para programar con c#, pero cuando realizo un programa sencillo, Al momento de ingresar los datos en la terminal esta repentinamente se cierra y no se lo que pueda causar esto codigo:

```
Estudiante[] estudiante = new Estudiante[n];

for (int i = 0; i < estudiante.Length; i++) 
{     
    estudiante[i] = new Estudiante();
    Console.WriteLine($"Ingrese el Nombre del estudiante {i + 1}");     
    estudiante[i].Nombre = 
    Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"Ingrese la Edad del Estudiante {i + 1}");     
    estudiante[i].Edad = Convert.ToUInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine($"Ingrese la nota final del Estudiante {i + 1}");
    estudiante[i].Nota_Final = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine()); 
}
```

Comment: Mira [ask] para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. También, aprovecha y haz el [tour] para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! en que momento? que error recibis? que esta esperando el programa, como es el programa? por no poner todo eso, te respondieron una respuesta valida, pero que no te sirve...

Comment: Muchas Gracias por las aclaraciones ya estoy haciendo las debidas correcciones muchas gracias

Comment: se cierra despues de ingreasr la ultima nota final???

Comment: Visual Studio o Visual Studio Code ?????

Comment: @gbianchi, no, en cualquiera se cierra, algunas veces corre bien completo y otra veces se cierra, puedes ser cuando se ingresa el nombre, la edad, la nota etc.,

Comment: @Yussef Visual Studio

Comment: Está raro el asunto, tienes alguna manera de hacer un pequeño video que muestre el problema?? Yo hice unas pruebas y no encontré manera de que cerrara la consola y que la depuración siguiera funcionando

Comment: @Yussef si aquí te dejo los videos subidos a drive, están comentados por mi ya que se lo mande a otra persona, [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dTA4FTnzn-p_eAiv-_o7sQ9LEh6D9eHB/view?usp=drive_link] y [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S4nDnn9jmoj-JfyNJ2Fcf-WBgHPQkT22/view?usp=drive_link]

Comment: El video corto muestra el comportamiento descrito que es bien anómalo. El video largo muestra una exception que es igual de rara. Click derecho en el proyecto->propiedades-> pestaña "Depurar" saca una foto y ponla en la pregunta

Comment: Por otro lado, has intentado crear un proyecto de cero nuevamente?? quizás eso soluciona tu problema, aunque igual me gustaría saber que lo origina.

Answer (score 1):

Para evitar salir de la terminal podrías poner como última linea de código:

```
Console.ReadLine();
```

De esta forma el programa se detendrá en esta instrucción esperando a que presiones cualquier tecla para que la consola se cierre.

## Actualización:

Prueba a ejecutar tu programa directamente desde la **consola de Windows**, para ello presiona las **teclas Windows + R** y escribe **cmd**, una vez que se abra la **consola de Windows** utiliza el **comando cd** para ejecutar tu proyecto, ejemplo:

```
cd D:\MisProyectos
```

Posteriormente escribe el nombre de tu ejecutable, ejemplo:

```
MiProyecto.exe
```

Y mira a ver si te ocurre el mismo error.

Otra cosa que podrías hacer es verificar que la **opción Cerrar automáticamente la consola cuando se detenga la depuración** esté desmarcada, para ello haz clic en el **menú Herramientas/Opciones** y en la ventana que se abre despliega la **opción Depuración** en el panel izquierdo, después da clic en la **opción General** y en el panel derecho asegúrate de desmarcar la **opción Cerrar automáticamente la consola cuando se detenga la depuración**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Lo otro que podrías probar es limpiar tu solución y volverla a compilar, para ello ve al **explorador de soluciones**, clic derecho sobre tu solución, y el menú que se despliega dar clic en la **opción Limpiar solución**, posteriormente darías clic en la o**pción Compilar solución** o **Recompilar solución**:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Agradezco tu respuesta, pero el error no es ese, resulta que me encuentro llenando los datos que me pide la terminal por simulación y mientras escribo se cierra, pero el visual code  sigue depurando, es la terminal que se cierra sola te dejo un fragmento del código para que tengas idea

Comment: `Estudiante[] estudiante = new Estudiante[n];
for (int i = 0; i < estudiante.Length; i++)
{
    estudiante[i] = new Estudiante();
    Console.WriteLine($"Ingrese el Nombre del estudiante {i + 1}");
    estudiante[i].Nombre = Console.ReadLine();
    Console.WriteLine($"Ingrese la Edad del Estudiante {i + 1}");
    estudiante[i].Edad = Convert.ToUInt16(Console.ReadLine());
    Console.WriteLine($"Ingrese la nota final del Estudiante {i + 1}");
    estudiante[i].Nota_Final = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
}`

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y pon el código en la pregunta

Comment: y por no pedir aclaraciones, terminamos con una respuesta valida, para otro escenario...

Comment: Y que haces después de ese fragmento de código @AsdrubalRendon

Comment: nada se cierra las llaves del for, y se van cerrando las llaves, una a una, las del main, las de namespace etc.

Comment: Cual es tu última linea de código? @AsdrubalRendon

Comment: @AsdrubalRendon te pido que pruebes mi respuesta, tú última linea de código debe ser la que te indico en mi respuesta, sino haces eso se cierra el programa

Comment: `                Console.WriteLine($"Ingrese la nota final del Estudiante {i + 1}");
                estudiante[i].Nota_Final = float.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
            }

        }
    }
}` hasta aqui llegaria mi programa

Comment: Debajo de esa línea haz lo que te digo

Comment: @AsdrubalRendon después de esa línea pon Console.ReadLine(); hazme caso

Comment: okey, esta bien lo intentare, muchas gracias y cualquier cosa te aviso, gracias.

Comment: @AsdrubalRendon lo único que tienes que hacer es lo que te indico, no entiendo por qué no me entiendes, tú problema se resuelve fácil

Comment: @Japv, entiendo tu preocupación hermano pero tal vez sea la manera en la cual me explico, ya realice un poco lo que me indicaste y no me sirvió, de igual forma queria dejarte por aqui un video para que observes bien lo que pasa [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1S4nDnn9jmoj-JfyNJ2Fcf-WBgHPQkT22/view?usp=drive_link%5D] junto a este [https://drive.google.com/file/d/1dTA4FTnzn-p_eAiv-_o7sQ9LEh6D9eHB/view?usp=drive_link%5D]

Comment: Antes de realizar una respuesta, es importante pedir aclaraciones, al final puedes trabajar en una respuesta y no es lo que necesita el OP.